# JS--custom image attributes

Tags: javascript, json, image, html

I need to be able to define the fact that [a board game tile like this one](http://russcon.org/RussCon/carcassonne/city1rsw.png) has a city on the top edge, roads on the left and bottom edge, and grass on the right edge.

How can I do this? From what I've read about HTML5 custom data attributes they seem like a viable option (e.g., "data-left='road'..."), but I am hoping to receive confirmation from someone with more coding experience before getting too far into the project. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom attributes like toske said, but I would recommend that you create a data object model representation (using JSON) of your scenario and them process this model to render your interface.

Edit: [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/URWT9/). The data is the tiles array that contains some objects that represents each tile. I used jQuery, but you can use the JavaScript library that you want. I recomment that you learn jQuery if you don't know how to use it. It's a very powerfull and simple library.

Comment: I used JQuery to create a calulator that shows the odds of drawing a given piece at any point during the game, so it seems logical to simply extend my JQuery model. Do I even need to get into JSON, with which I am totally unfamiliar, if I use JQuery objects like you demonstrated?

Comment: Hi. I think you must become familiar with JSON because its used a lot. It's very easy to understand. JSON is a data interchange format, like XML. The sintax that I used to create the array of tiles is not properly JSON, but it is almost the same. In your software, you will create the javascript objects using JSON (at the server) and them get these data in your JavaScript client code, that will convert the JSON representation (a string) to objects. Take a look here http://json.org/ In the footer, there are lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use custom data attributes in HTML 5. Just prefix them with "data-" e.g.

```
<img src="foo.jpg" data-some-arbitrary-attribute="foo" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can definitely put custom attributes in HTML5 tags, like:

```
    <img left-connection="road" right-connection="railroad"... />
```

though I would rather advice to just mark img tags with id, and then have a JSON object that maps ID's to connectivity data like:

```
    <img id="a11" src="..." />

    <script type="text/javascript> 
       var connectivityData = { a11 : { left : 'road',right:'railroad'}}
    </script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your attributes be prefixed with "data-"?

Comment: The `left-connection` or `right-connection` attributes are not HTML5; they would be if it was `data-left-connection`. The difference is that the `data` part is actually supported. You can find out more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes)

Comment: You're right, my apologies,attributes must have data- prefix.